# Database view listing distinct days

Tags: postgresql, view, materialized-view, python

I have a list of sensors of many machines, that stores on a second base (i.e., 86400 records each day for each machine). One of the many columns is the datetime of the value (that can also be stored separately as date and time). 
I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.

Frequently, I need to find out what dates have sensor's records available for each machine.

I thought about creating a database view of distinct dates for each machine, but after searching for "materialized views" I think I'm ok with updating this list once in a while each day, as data is stored daily.

Would anyone give any advice about doing it?

The table is similar to

```
ID | Machine_code | Sensor_1 | Sensor_2 | Sensor3 | Datetime
1  | Drimmer      | 12       |  15.8    | 13.4    | 2016-03-03 10:00:03 GMT+1
```

If it helps anyhow, I'm using Django Framework in front of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create materialized view foo as 
  select distinct machine_code, date(datetime) from thing;

create unique index on foo(machine_code,date);
```

Beware that the conversion of datetime to date will occur in the timezone of whoever last created or refreshed the MV.  You might want to use this instead:

```
create materialized view foo as 
  select distinct machine_code, date(datetime at time zone 'GMT+1') from thing;
```

But that might not do what you want with daylight savings time.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think with this materialized view, I'll be able to refresh it daily and have it updated as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you wanted something like this

```
Create table dummy
(
  Mymachine int,
  Myval int,
  Mysense date
);

 Insert into dummy Values (1, 2, '2016-02-25');
 Insert into dummy values (1, 3, '2016-02-26');
 Insert into dummy Values (2, 4, '2016-02-24');
 Insert into dummy Values (2, 5, '2016-02-25');
 Insert into dummy Values (2, 6, '2016-02-27');
 Insert into dummy Values (2, 2, '2016-02-25');
```

And then specify a given range in your query, thus:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Mymachine, DATE(Mysense) FROM dummy
Where date(Mysense) in
(
  SELECT (generate_series('2016-02-15', '2016-03-10', '1 day'::interval))::DATE
);
```

p.s. don't call a field `datetime` - it's a reserved word in SQL, plus it makes debugging more difficult!

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'll follow your recommendation about not using `datetime`. In fact, right now I'm using `timestamp`. Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't use that either - AFAIK, `timestamp` is also reserved! As well as making debugging a pain, apps that point at databases with these kind of field names are a nightmare to port. Since you liked my answer, maybe you could see your way to giving me a +1? :-)